# 2006 Nissan Maxima transmission

Tags: transmission, part-identification, maxima

[image]I removed the transmission from a 2006 nissan maxima and have a 2 3/4" metal ring with teeth pressed into it and I don't remember where it goes

Comment: Do you have a picture? There is no way most of us could even start to guess at what the heck you are talking about ;-)

Comment: It *looks* like a Torrington bearing, but I wouldn't have a clue where you'd have gotten it from ... did you rebuild the transmission? Why did you have it out of the vehicle? Is this an automatic transmission or standard?

Comment: automatic trans, It could have come from something I removed to get tranny out